# Activity for locking android device

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible make an activity, that will lock the android device?

---

- That device would be unlocked only after entering right PIN number.
- During lock, user can't call,message, and can't view notifications,contacts,call logs,storage data,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can take advantage of the [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) introduced in Android 2.2. This does require the user to accept that your application wants to have control of the device but obviously you would need to disclose that information anyway. Also it should be noted that on a phone (at least in the US) you must **always** have access to make emergency phone calls.

Using the API you can enforce a pin lock be set and also invoke the lock screen at will in addition to many other administration features.